# Android: Navigation menu not working with button but with touch

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

Hiho!

I build a navigation drawer into my android app. I used the howto from http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android and modified it at one place of the layout. I can activate the menu when i touch and swing my finger from left to right. But if I touch the hamburger menu nothing hapend. What ist wrong? 
If i swipped in the menu the icon changed to an arrow, so there is a connection.
Hope some one can help me.

My Java Class (Main Activity):

```
public class AmericanFootball extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MenuItem mi;
    public static Context context;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = (Context) this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_american_football);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getText(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        checkInternet ci = new checkInternet();
        boolean internet=ci.isNetzwerkVerfuegbar((Context) this);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);
        tv.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface((Context) this, FontManager.FONTAWESOME));
        tv.setText(R.string.fa_icon_areachart);
        tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryLight));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_american_football, menu);

        MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);

        TextDrawable td = new TextDrawable((Context) this);
        td.setText(getString(R.string.fa_refresh));
        td.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        td.setTextSize(30);
        mi.setIcon(td);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh, null);
        iv.setImageDrawable(td);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            doRefreshGames(item);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(AmericanFootball.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}
```

My layoutfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="k0f.de.americanfootball.AmericanFootball">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_american_football" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Forgot a little thing:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
}
```